# How to fetch inner node of JSON using freemarker?

Tags: json, freemarker

Sample JSON:

```
{
  "results": [
  {
   "_id": "12345",
   "CustomerAccount": {
     "Status": "ACTIVE",
     "Address": [
      {
        "FormatCode": "PRIM",
        "FreeFormatAddress": "ENGLAND"
      },
      {
        "FormatCode": "SEC",
        "FreeFormatAddress": "IRELAND"
      }
    ]
   },
  "LegalVehicleID": "01",
  "BrokerAccount": {
    "Status": "ACTIVE",
    "Address": [
      {
        "FormatCode": "PRIM123",
        "FreeFormatAddress": "SG"
      },
      {
        "FormatCode": "SEC123",
        "FreeFormatAddress": "IND"
      }
    ]
  }
 }
 ]
}
```

So i want to get Address as list regardless of CustomerAccount or BrokerAccount.

`result.*.Address` and then access `FormatCode` and `FreeFormatAddress` using FreeMarker.

Please let me know how to do so thanks.

Comment: Why don't you deserialize the JSON to a Java object first?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such feature in the template language itself. Such things can be achieved with a `TemplateModel` that was designed to do queries against JSON, similarly as such queries are possible against XML (W3C DOM to be more precise) out-of-the-box. But I'm not aware of anybody has written such thing for JSON (and even then it's question what Java objects represent the JSON... like, is it Jackson `JsonNode`-s?).